# Wave keeps muting

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio

The sound on my computer keeps muting. When I check the volume control thing the wave is turned all the way down for some reason.

I can't think what's doing this.

Comment: Have you run any virus scans recently? Checked for trojans? Is this on a laptop that has a touch-slider that controls the volume? Please provide more information.

Comment: Everything's clean and it's nothing to do with that :p